# "Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) : invalid first argument"

Tags: r, function, sampling

I'm trying to run a function for sampling but keep getting an error that I can't find a way around as it's not specified anywhere in my code. Here's the error

"Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) :
invalid first argument"

My Code:

```
idpSample <- function(x) {

main.sample <- sample(
idp.frame[COUNTY == idp.breakdown[x, County], GEOID9],
idp.breakdown[x, idp_cluster],
prob = idp.frame[COUNTY == idp.breakdown[x, County], mt12_est_idps_hh],
replace = T 
)

 n.reserve <- min(3, ifelse(
 nrow(idp.frame[COUNTY == idp.breakdown[x, County]]) - idp.breakdown[x, idp_cluster] <
  0,0,
nrow(idp.frame[COUNTY == idp.breakdown[x, County]]) - idp.breakdown[x, idp_cluster]
))
if(n.reserve>0){
reserve.sample <- sample(
  idp.frame[COUNTY == idp.breakdown[x, County] & GEOID9 %nin% main.sample, GEOID9],
  n.reserve,
  prob = idp.frame[COUNTY == idp.breakdown[x, County] & GEOID9 %nin% main.sample, 
  mt12_est_idps_hh],
  replace = F 
)
}else{
reserve.sample <- c()
 }

 data.frame(
 GEOID9 = c(main.sample, reserve.sample),
 sample_type = c(rep("Main sample", idp.breakdown[x, idp_cluster]),
                rep("Reserve",  n.reserve)))
}

idp.sample <- rbindlist(lapply(1:nrow(idp.breakdown), idpSample))
```

#sample dataframe

head(idp.breakdown)

```
                   State    County idp_cluster idp_n ret_cluster ret_n hc_cluster hc_n total_cluster total_n
1: Abyei Administrative Area     Abyei          11   143          11   143         11  143            33     429
2:         Central Equatoria      Juba           5    65           3    39          4   52            12     156
3:         Central Equatoria Kajo-Keji           1    13           3    39          8  104            12     156
4:         Central Equatoria    Lainya           4    52           2    26          4   52            10     130
5:         Central Equatoria    Morobo           5    65           3    39          3   39            11     143
6:         Central Equatoria  Terekeka           1    13           1    13         10  130            12     156
```

head(idp.frame)

```
STA_CODE      STATE CTY_CODE COUNTY PAY_CODE BOM_CODE FSNMS_Urban mt12_est_idps_ind mt12_est_idps_hh
1:       71 Upper Nile       01   Renk       01      001       FALSE              1677              304
2:       71 Upper Nile       01   Renk       01      003       FALSE              1104              184
3:       71 Upper Nile       01   Renk       01      004       FALSE               161               31
4:       71 Upper Nile       01   Renk       02      001       FALSE                87               16
5:       71 Upper Nile       01   Renk       02      003       FALSE               796              159
6:       71 Upper Nile       01   Renk       02      006       FALSE               419               82

mt12_est_rets_ind mt12_est_rets_hh    PAYAM      BOMA    GEOID9
1:              5087             1010 Chemmedi Bebineeth 710101001
2:              9446             1892 Chemmedi  Chemmedi 710101003
3:              1766              347 Chemmedi    Labior 710101004
4:              6854             1349    Geger   Gerbena 710102001
5:             26238             5147    Geger  Gospamni 710102003
6:              5967             1195    Geger   Wunthow 710102006
```

Comment: You are using `sample()` which is probably where the error is coming from. I suspect that `idp.frame[COUNTY == idp.breakdown[x, County] & GEOID9 %nin% main.sample, GEOID9]` doesn't return a single `numeric` value as required by `sample(n=)`.

Comment: How would you advise I get around it? I'm not entirely sure how to make it return a numeric value. Also to mention that the script works fine on a dataset from last year